# Place button at bottom of bottom sheet in flutter

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet

I have a bottom sheet where i have an TypeAheadFormField and i want to place a button at the end of bottom sheet.

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 32.h),
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Text(
        "Email",
        style: TextStyle(
            letterSpacing: -0.3,
            color: Helper.textColor700,
            fontSize: 14.sp,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 6.h),
      TypeAheadFormField(),
      TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // Handle the button click
        },
        child: const Text('Sample Button'),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

how can i place button at the end